# solution for div causing x scrolling in browsers

Tags: html, css

Please see example: http://jsfiddle.net/H5x9N/

I have a page that aligns to center, 1020px wide. I then want ads on the left and right of it contained in divs that do not cause scrolling.

here is part of the code that will display the ads:

```
.majorad-container {
height: 1px;
left: 50%;
margin: auto auto auto -1250px;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
width: 2500px;
z-index: 20;
}
.adscrollleft {
background: url("") repeat-y scroll right top #0A080B;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
height: 120px;
margin-top: -20px;
width: 720px;
}
.adscrollright {
background: url("") repeat-y scroll left top #0A080B;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
height: 120px;
margin-top: -20px;
width: 720px;
}
```

If i use position: fixed for .majorad-container - no x scrolling, but i want the ad to scroll up with the page.

I hope that explains my problem well, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

make the ad's background images and than use background cover

```
#divname{
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height:0%;
    max-height:100%;

}
```

Comment: i don't understand your answer, could you go into more detail?

Comment: take a look over here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp